# Ignore PathNotFoundException during mutations using Java couchbase SDK

Tags: java, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I am using java couchbase sdk in my application. I am using **AsyncMutateInBuilder** for doing mutations. Now when i upsert a mutation or try to remove a path which doesn't exist in the document, I get PathNotFoundException which makes sense.

While upserting the mutation, I am using [SubDocOptionsBuilder](https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.4.7/com/couchbase/client/java/subdoc/SubdocOptionsBuilder.html) to create a path if it doesn't exist before upserting a mutation. This is how it looks like-

**mutator.upsert(this.path, this.data, new SubdocOptionsBuilder().createPath(Boolean.TRUE))**

This works perfectly fine and. Now I want to achieve the same results while removing a path from document. If the path doesn't exist, I don't want to end up with **PathNotFoundException**. I would just like to move on. Is there a way i can achieve this?

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? I just tried this with the latest .NET SDK, and I did not get an exception when trying to remove a path that doesn't exist (and I would expect that behavior from the Java SDK too).

Comment: I am using sdk 2.7.2.